# Flopy code for vertical conductance (vcont) bcf file

Tags: flopy

I have a two layer model. The top layer in unconfined and the bottom layer is confined. I can not seem to get my flopy models vertical conductance to match the results of a PMWIN model where it is computed automatically within the program. 
Here is the relevant bit of code:

## MODEL DIMENSIONS

```
nlay = 2   # number of layers

nrow = 80   # number of rows

ncol = 57   # number of columns

laytyp = [1,0] #unconfined top layer, confined aquifer below

zbot = -300 # bottom of aquifer same for entire model
```

### Elevations for each model layer (top & bottom) is imported from text-file:

```
Model_Top_Elevation = np.loadtxt('model_top_elev.txt', dtype=np.float32)

Model_Top_Elevation  = np.array([Model_Top_Elevation])

Lay1_Bottom_Elevation= np.loadtxt('bottom_lay1.txt', dtype=np.float32)
```

# bottom elevation of Layer 1 is imported from txt file

```
Lay1_Bottom_Elevation= np.loadtxt('bottom_lay1.txt', dtype=np.float32)
Lay1_Bottom_Elevation  = np.array([Lay1_Bottom_Elevation])

Lay2_Top_Elevation = np.loadtxt('top_lay2.txt', dtype=np.float32)
Lay2_Top_Elevation  = np.array([Lay2_Top_Elevation])
```

### DETERMINE AQUIFER THICKNESS of each model layer:

```
Lay1_Width = -1*(Lay1_Bottom_Elevation-Model_Top_Elevation)

Lay2_Width = -1*(-1*Lay2_Top_Elevation + -300)
```

### Calculate Lay 1 aquifer thickness if it begins from watertable (not top elevation):

```
Initial head = 211

Lay1_Watertable_Width = -1*(Lay1_Bottom_Elevation-Initial head)
```

### Hydraulic conductivity of 10m/d adopted for entire model

```
hk = 10
```

### Vertical conductivity

```
vk = 0.00001*np.ones((nlay, nrow, ncol), dtype=np.float32)
```

### Calculate transmissivity of layer 2

```
T = hk*(Lay2_Width)
```

### Calculate vertical conductance (vcont)

```
vcont = 1/(((Lay1_Watertable_Width)/ vk[0])+((Lay2_Width*0.5)/ vk[1]))
```

### Write BCF File:

```
bcf = flopy.modflow.ModflowBcf(mf,ipakcb=50,laycon=[1,0], hdry=-1e+30, iwdflg=0, wetfct=0.1, iwetit=1, ihdwet=0, trpy = [1,0],hy=hk, vcont=vcont,tran=[0,T])
```

#### MODEL OUTPUT DOES NOT MATCH PMWIN CALCULATION FOR VCONT

If anyone has any recommendations as to where I am going wrong please help!

[image: I have attached the formula according to the PMWIN manual]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your VCONT calculation may have an error in it. Here is what it should be:

```
vcont = 1 / ((0.5 * Lay1_Watertable_Width / vk[0]) + (0.5 * Lay_2_width / vk[1]))
```

I am also confused by you having a different array for `'bottom_lay1.txt'` and `'top_lay2.txt'`, because the bottom of layer 1 is the top of layer 2 for MODFLOW.